# how does Axis decide which method in the skeleton should be called when a request comes from a external client like soapui?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, axis

when I send a request to a **web-service** from any external client ,then I am using document style binding with literal encoding .Thus there is no operation name in my message when it reaches the webservice. So then how does Axis decide which operation of the **web-service** should be called.

Comment: You can check answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745501/how-does-the-soap-server-determine-which-operation-it-should-perform/26758325#26758325

Comment: Any answer for this question.